# Sum of Digits using tostring and number methods javascript

Tags: javascript, tostring

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong in this problem? I want to add the sum of the `num` variable using `toString` and `Number` methods. I first turn `num` into the string `num = '12345'`. Then I loop through string, turn it into a number and add it to the sum.

```
var num = 12345;

function sumDigits(num) {     
  var sumOfDigits = 0;     
  num.toString();     
  for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++){    
    sumOfDigits += Number(num[i]);     
  }     
  return sumOfDigits;    
}
```

Comment: You need to use charAt because it's a string, not an array.  You could make that work if you did num.toString().split('');

Comment: You are not saving the result of, `toString()`

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the result of `num.toString()` to anything.

```js
var num = 12345;

function sumDigits(num) {
  var sumOfDigits = 0;
  num = num.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    sumOfDigits += Number(num[i]);
  }
  return sumOfDigits;
}

console.log(sumDigits(num));
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

You can use split, map and reduce to split the array, map it to integers, then use a reduce function to sum the integers.

You could eliminate the map if you want to move parse into the reduce, but I like to keep the steps separate.

```js
var num = 12345;

function sumDigits(num) {     
var sumOfDigits = num
                  .toString()
                  .split('')
                  .map(function(n) { return parseInt(n);})
                  .reduce(function(acc, val) {
                            return acc + val;
                           }, 
                           0
                  );
  return sumOfDigits;

}

var sum = sumDigits(num);
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Bracket notation for strings is an ECMAScript 5 feature. It's widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this one :

```
    var num = 12345;
    function sumDigits(num) {
    //empty variable
    var str;
    //check type of the incoming value
    (typeof num == "string") ? str = num : str = num.toString();
    //this is the same with above if you don't know how to use short handed if else 
    /*
        if(typeof num == "string"){
            str = num;
        } else {
            str = num.toString();
        }
    */
    //Array's split Method and a variable which u have create already
    var arr = str.split(''), sumOfDigits = 0;
    for(var i in arr){
        //You should use parseInt() method.
        sumOfDigits += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    //return the sum of the digits
    return sumOfDigits;
};
console.log(sumDigits(num));
```

If you have future problems please first search a bit then write here :)